# Not able to override method with generics

Tags: java, generics

I have following methods defined in interface

```
public interface Stack<T> {
    void method1(T element);
    T method2();
}
```

Class Implementing this interface implements these methods as follows

```
private List<T> elements;

@Override
public void method1(T element) {
    elements.add(element);
}

@Override
public T method2() {
    return elements.remove(elements.size() - 1);
}
```

With this I get following error for method1: Method does not override method from super class, while method2 works fine.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `T`defined in your interface and implementing class?

Comment: I would bet a nickel, that you have something like this `class YourClass<T> implements Stack`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly fine:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    interface MyStack<T> {
        void push(T item);
        T pop();
    }

    static class MyStackImpl<T> implements MyStack<T> {
        private List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
        @Override
        public void push(T item) {
            items.add(item);
        }

        @Override
        public T pop() {
            return items.remove(items.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack<Integer> stack = new MyStackImpl<Integer>();
        stack.push(42);
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add type parameter to the interface and to the class too:

```
public interface Stack<T> { // here it is: <T>

    void method1(T element);

    T method2();
}

public class Impl<T> implements Stack<T> { // and here too

    private List<T> elements;

    @Override
    public void method1(T element) {
        elements.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public T method2() {
        return elements.remove(elements.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that OPs interface already accepts a generic type, but it wasn't shown due to an incorrect formatting. I guess OP forgot to add the generic type in his class, like `class Impl<T> implements Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the interface's generic type `interface Stack<T>`.

```
public interface Stack<T> {

    void method1(T element);

    T method2();
}
```

And you also need to define the generic type in you implementation `class YourStack<T>`

```
class YourStack<T> implements Stack<T>{

    private List<T> elements;

    @Override
    public void method1(T element) {
        elements.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public T method2() {
        return elements.remove(elements.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that OPs interface already accepts a generic type, but it wasn't shown due to an incorrect formatting. I guess OP forgot to add the generic type in his class, like `class YourStack<T> implements Stack`.